# How can I append a date or time to an image and prevent it from caching using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I created the following javascript code that appends a new date and time on click so that the browser does not pick up the image from the cache and loads it everytime. My code is:

```
$(#button).click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   $('.Myimage').attr('src',$('this').src + 'Testimage.png' + '?' + (new Date().getTime()));
});
```

This almost works fine but I'm getting an **undefined** message at the beginning of my image string.

```
<img src="undefinedTestimage.png?1628621212728" class="Myimage">
```

I'm not sure why. I figure that its some sort of typo. I'm also open to improving the code. Suggestions?

Comment: `$('this')` is looking for a `<this>` element. There's no such element in your document, so `.src` is undefined.

Comment: Chenge `$('this')` for `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('this')` is selecting a `<this>` element.

If you change it to `$(this)` it still won't be correct, because `this` is the button, not the image. Also, in jQuery you use `.attr('src')` to get the `src` attribute, not `.src`.

If you want to get the image's `src`, you need to loop over all the `.Myimage` elements. You can do that by giving a function argument to the `.attr()` method. This receives the old attribute as an argument, and returns the new value.

You don't need to concatenate `Testimage.png`, since that should already be in the `src`.

```js
$('#button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.Myimage').attr('src', (i, src) =>
    src + '?' + (new Date().getTime()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="foo.png" class="Myimage">
<img src="bar.png" class="Myimage">
<br>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: Fixed the syntax and tested.